# cannot implicitly convert type string[] to model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

depending on this answer [AllowHtml doesn't work with Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257752/allowhtml-doesnt-work-with-array) I did the required changes to follow the answer but getting an error on assign values to array `vls.HtmlTexts =  form.GetValues(keys[i]);` "cannot implicitly convert type string[] to model"

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
String[] keys = form.AllKeys;
HtmlValuesCollection vls = new HtmlValuesCollection();

for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
{
    vls.HtmlTexts =  form.GetValues(keys[i]); 
    for (int j = 0; j < vls.HtmlTexts.Length; j++)
    {
        output.Append(vls.HtmlTexts[j]);
    }
    if (i < keys.Length-1)
    {
        output.Append(",");
    }
}

public class HtmlValues
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public String HtmlText { get; set; }
}

public class HtmlValuesCollection
{
    public HtmlValues [] HtmlTexts { get; set; }
}
```

Any Advise ?

Comment: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473548/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-model

Comment: could u plz show your `ValuesCollection`?

Comment: try this => `public class ValuesCollection
    {
        [AllowHtml]
        public string[] Values { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: is above class definition working?

Comment: @ershoaib No. it's not working

Comment: @user1010941, its not working means? the above error as it is or your code logic not working?

Comment: @ershoaib the code logic is correct. The error here `vls.HtmlTexts =  form.GetValues(keys[i]);` when the code change to `String[] values = form.GetValues(keys[i]);` it's working but not accepting htmlvalue

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the result to the actual array type you want

```
(HtmlValues[])form.GetValues(keys[i]);
```

as GetValues isn't strongly typed.

Comment: It's getting new error with previous one (Cast is redundant)

Comment: I've used this code from [link](https://selectpdf.com/demo-mvc/ViewHttpPostData) . it's working fine but I need to pass html code. I did some changed but the error still appear